# port scanner not working in a python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, terminal

```
import colorama
from colorama import Fore,Back
import time
import os
import sys
import socket
from menu import minimenu
from menu import textlogo
from colorama import init
import nmap
import re
import ipaddress
init(autoreset=True)

hostname=socket.gethostname()   
LocalIP=socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
nmScan = nmap.PortScanner()


while True:
    textlogo()
    minimenu()

    command = input (Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + ">- ")
    if command == "exit":
        break
    elif command == "clear":
        os.system("cls")
        
        
# network scan
    elif command == "port scan":
        port_range_pattern = re.compile("([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)")
        port_min = 0
        port_max = 65535
        open_ports = []
        ip_add_entered = input(Fore.MAGENTA + "\nIP To Scan: ")
        print("")
        time.sleep(1)
        for port in range(port_min, port_max + 1):
            with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
                s.settimeout(2)
                s.connect((ip_add_entered, port))
                open_ports.append(port)           
        for port in open_ports:
            print(Fore.MAGENTA + f"Port {port} is open on {ip_add_entered}.")
```

comes back with a s.connect((ip_add_entered, port)) ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused error

didn't work for me at all and just comes back with the error.
Did anyone make one of these before?
ps. remove the > textlogo() < and the > minimenu() < to make this work on your system, those 2 things are just a logo and menu that pops up at the top of the screen

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), you can delete not-related logic such as  `if command == "exit"`

Comment: Well, isn't "Connection Refused" the expected result if there is no process listening on that specific port?  `s.connect` throws an exception, if it can't connect. You have to catch that exception somewhere ...

Comment: how would u suggest i fix this so it works then?

Comment: As I said. Use exception handling. Ie if no exception is thrown, consider the port as open. If a ConnectionRefusedError is thrown, consider it as not open ... https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: oh ok thanks, tho... i had checked the ip for open ports with a different scanner and it had come back saying there was a 80,8080 and one other that i cant remember. its going from a port range of 0-65535 which should cover them all...